# SQL Query in Java - Unable to select two columns

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I currently have a search function for my database where I have a Java front-end GUI.

At the moment in Java I have a SELECT statement that checks what one enters is LIKE something.  The problem that I am having is that within my SELECT statement, I want to also get the forename column.(I am fairly new to this).

Below is a snippet of the code:

```
 /*
 * Search method
 */
public void search()
{       
    // search function - person query
    String sqlPerson = " SELECT * FROM `person` "
                         + "WHERE ((`person`.`Surname`LIKE ?) "
                         + "OR (`person`.`Forename` LIKE ?) "
                         + "OR (`person`.`Person_Id` LIKE ?) "
                         + "OR (`person`.`aka` LIKE ?) "
                         + ")ORDER BY `person`.`Surname` ASC ";
```

Does anyone know how I can select both forename and surname so it gets both columns because at the moment when I search, I can only do it by one column (As I am currently using an OR).

Thanks

Comment: Your query already selects all columns by using the `*`.

Comment: There isn't enough code to say what's wrong with it. I can make a guess: You have to supply a parameter for each "?" in the query, but you have only supplied a parameter for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Your query already gets all colums from that table. What is your problem? Just replace the correct ? with the search term you are looking for.